# avoid onCreate() function call of activity when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities, activity A and activity B. Both the activities have fragments. Activity A calls activity B. 
When activity B is called and I press back button, on medium screen size the following function sequence is called.

`onResume()` of activity A.

but when activity B is called and I press back button, on **large screen size (10.1')** the following function sequence is called.

`onCreate()` of activity A.
`onCreateView()` of the fragment associated with activity A.
`onResume()` of Activity A.

Both the activities are restricted to **portrait mode** in the manifest and I also used

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

for each activity in the manifest.

What I want is, that the application behave like it behaves on the medium screen size. i.e i don't want `onCreate()` of activity A to be called when I press the Back Button.

Any help will br appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can. My understanding is that the Android system can kill any activity that is inactive, if it needs the memory, and then the Activity object will be re-created when it is to be shown again. You were just lucky that the medium size version wasn't killed.

Comment: Ummmm according to the android documentation the activity A should get paused and when I come back from activity B, it should just resume. This is what i get on all my other application. :/

Comment: Makes no sense. This isn't standard behaviour. Can you tell if, after you start Activity B on the large screen device, `ActivityA.onDestroy()` is being called? If so, maybe that device has the developer flag "Don;t keep activities" enabled

Answer (score 0):

Save your activity state in `onsaveinstancestate()` then check for the bundle before all the onCreate code.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html